# Asymptotic Expansion for integral with a moving maxima

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-method

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t-x / t^{2}} d t$$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

I understand that this is a Laplace integral with a moving maximum and that I will need to rescale to get a new variable $s=tx^{-1/3}$ to convert the integral into a standard Laplace integral. I know how to solve the problem as $x \rightarrow \infty$ (two bounds of $s$ is from 0 to $\infty$). However, when  $x \rightarrow 0$ the two bounds for two bounds of $s$ should also be from $0$ to $\infty$. then what is the difference between these two limits?

Comment: The difference is that you don't get an integrand amenable to Laplace's method, the exponent is a function of $s$ times a small parameter, not times a large parameter. Since $|f(x, t)| \leq e^{-t}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x, t)$ exists, the leading term is given by
$$\int_0^\infty \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x, t) \, dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

*Without Laplace method.*

Using algebra, this integral involves the [Meijer G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function)
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-t-\frac{x}{t^2}}\,dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\,G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{x}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{2},1
\end{array}
\right)\qquad \text{if} \qquad \Re(x)>0$$

Expanded around $x=0$,
$$I=1-\sqrt{\pi x} -\frac{1}{2} x \left(\log (x)+2 \gamma -1-2\log (2)-\psi
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+O\left(x^{3/2}\right)$$